# a specific verse in Ibn Ishaq's "Sirat Rasulallah" in Arabic

Tags: prophet-muhammad, arabic, hadith-interpretation

I am trying to find the Arabic equivalent to this text:

> [Muhammad said] "So I read it, and he [Gabriel] departed from me. And I awoke from my sleep, and it was as though these words were written on my heart […]. I thought, Woe is me poet or possessed—Never shall Quraysh say this of me! I will go to the top of the mountain and throw myself down that I may kill myself and gain rest. So I went forth to do so and then when I was midway on the mountain, I heard a voice from heaven saying, "O Muhammad! thou art the apostle of God and I am Gabriel."

which can be found on this site (p.106): https://archive.org/details/TheLifeOfMohammedGuillaume

this site contains the Arabic original version: https://archive.org/stream/Sirat_Ibn_Ishaq#page/n122/mode/2up
 but I can't read Arabic so I don't know where (on what page) it is. would appreciate some help finding it. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The passage that you are looking for is on page 168, bottom half of the page, in the edition in your link.

Answer (score 1):

The text goes like:

> قال : فقرأته ، قال : ثم انتهى ، ثم انصرف عني وهببت من نومي ، وكأنما كتب في قلبي كتابا .
>   قال : ولم يكن من خلق الله أحد أبغض إلى من شاعر أو مجنون ، كنت لا أطيق أن أنظر إليهما ، قال : قلت إن الأبعد - يعني نفسه - لشاعر أو مجنون ، لا تحدث بها عني قريش أبدا ! لأعمدنّ إلى حالقٍ من الجبل فلأطرحنّ نفسي منه أقتلها فلأستريح . قال : فخرجت أريد ذلك ، حتى إذا كنت في وسط من الجبل ، سمعت صوتا من السماء يقول : يا محمد ، أنت رسول الله ، وأنا جبريل ..) .

As aasheq mentioned it is indeed on page 168, however, please do keep in mind that the Bukhari and Alhafid Ibn Hajir both said this is a weak hadith.

Additionally, another narration with similar text by Imam Altabri is refused by connection and people (Sanad and Matan).

Explanation on why many scholars say this is a fake hadith includes people who never met the Prophet but yet reported it, a full explanation in Arabic is found here:

http://www.islamweb.net/mohammad/index.php?group=articles&lang=A&id=143616